# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'field2'

Tags: odoo

I have a problem when i use domain to compare two integer fields ?

```
_name = 'y'
'field1': fields.integer('Field1'), 
'field2': fields.integer('Field2'),

_name = 'x' 
'y_id': fields.many2one('y', 'Y', domain="[('field1','>','field2')]"),
```

=> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'field2'

Comment: Are you supposed to use quotes there? It seems like it's trying to parse 'field2' (literal string) as an int.

Comment: ok but now how i compare field1 and field2 in domaine ?